Access resources of Maven dependensies with "provided" scope
I coudn't undestand how to deal with Maven dependensies with "provided" scope. I'm trying to get resources (e.g. Json) from a library during the compile time and I have no idea how to do it.
It seems impossible.
I've tried to find recources using:

PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver
ClassLoader
env.Filer().getResource(StandardLocation.SOURCE_OUTPUT,"","name.json") (Annotation Processing)

I'll be glad to get a link of documentation that has an information where to look for resources which are in dependensies with provided scope. Thanks.

Asking for off-site resources is off-topic for Stackoverflow. Try focusing on the actual issue and provide details.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
